# How to solve x-frame-options' to 'sameorigin' in Laravel Shopify App

Tags: laravel, shopify-app

I'm using Larvel shopify package to make a shopify app with Laravel all setup are done but I faced a problem that' I can't solve. Please help me. here is the package link

https://github.com/osiset/laravel-shopify/wiki/Installation

[image]

Comment: Make sure you are applying auth.shopify middleware to your route

Comment: ``Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
})->middleware(['auth.shopify'])->name('home');``

Comment: I use route like this

Comment: is appbridge_enabled true in config/shopify-app.php?

Comment: `` 'appbridge_enabled' => (bool) env('SHOPIFY_APPBRIDGE_ENABLED', true),``

Comment: is the bridge correct ?

Comment: Here is my github code 

https://github.com/joneyspark/wishlist-spark

Comment: Make sure your APP_URL in env matches your actual URL

Comment: ``APP_URL=https://wishlist.joneyspark.com``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215900/discussion-between-joney-spark-and-divyank).

Comment: Not working yet